# securely using Nextcloud on raspberry pi

Tags: privacy, docker, raspberry-pi

I like data privacy, so I would like to set up a system that allows me to exchange data such as photos with family and friends. I have a raspberry pi (version 4 I think? the one that was new in the previous winter) running with OpenMediaVault5 to exchange documents within our home network. But now I would like a solution that also allows data sharing with people outside of our network.

I don't know so much about IT security, so please link me to the relevant concepts or briefly explain. I know that I have to

a) protect my data that I want to share online from being stolen/accessed by not authorised people

b) protect my home network behind my router from being attacked, because otherwise our computers can be attacked, too.

Hope that is correct so far.

I found [this explanation](https://dbtechreviews.com/2020/03/how-to-install-nextcloud-on-openmedivault-5-with-remote-access-and-ssl/) about installing Nextcloud on top of OpenMediaVault. Unfortunately, they don't really explain, whether this is secure and why it is secure, if it is.

I figured out the following:

- Using Docker is a good idea, because it makes setup easy and adds a layer between the outer world and my raspy os. Also OMV has kind of taken over my raspy, so I don't know if I would be able to run nginx/apache locally.
- Using a reverse proxy and lets encrypt secures and hides the way to the raspy os.
- Mounting an OMV-controlled directory for data makes sure that no-one can escape from my Docker container (as is described as possible [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152978/is-it-possible-to-escalate-privileges-and-escaping-from-a-docker-container)).

Is that correct? Is that secure enough? Do I need to learn more about the concepts to use them? Is there some risk that I totally neglected so far?

Comment: what do you intend reverse- proxying from? are you saying that your users would need to reverse-proxy to connect to nextcloud, or are you going to reverse-proxy your nextcloud instance to a separate public-facing host, for example, shared hosting?

Comment: (ie. i your users will 'reverse-proxy' to use nextcloud, actually you're just saying they will need to connect to the device using some other mechanism, such as a vpn tunnel, and then use their browser for nextcloud)

Comment: @anjuta: ""Is that correct?" - there are too many questions in single post. Please put them into separate questions. "Is that secure enough?" - this is very abstract. "enough" - it is opinions based. Make your question more specific.

Comment: I don't know how to be any more specific. As clearly written above, I don't know much about information security. That's why I asked about a) risks in my plan and b) certain pieces of technology.